# How to implement chat between users in a Django blog website ?

Tags: python, django, web, chat, blogs

Currently I'm working on a small project (for a course in University) that is building a blog website and I decided to use Django framework version 2.1.4, my python version is 3.7.1. One of the required feature for this blog website is: User can add others as friends, and he can see the list of his friends who are online and choose 1 of them to chat with. I'm getting stuck to find an efficient way to implement that feature, can anyone suggest a proper solution ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: im pretty sure you want django-channels for this ... either that or use a database and some kind of polling

Comment: You will need django channels for chatting